# Gridview changing data with respect to time

Tags: asp.net, ajax, sql-server-2008, gridview, asp.net-ajax

I am working on Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2008
I want to create an app in which my Gridview should change data (displayed in website) 
 with respect to time

---

means say

```
col1  | col2 
name1 |  age1 
name2 |  age2 
name3 |  age3

after 10 sec say 
col1  | col2 
name4 |  age4 
name5 |  age5 
name6 |  age6
```

Can any one help me out?

Comment: do you want to refresh your gridview every 10 seconds? Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes u can say refresh but with next available date in table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way is to use the ASP.NET AJAX timer control: http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/timer-control/  After 10 seconds, the tick event fires, and you can wrap everything in an UpdatePanel to give the user the full AJAX feel.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) : Comet is a web application model in which a long-held HTTP request allows a web server to push data to a browser, without the browser explicitly requesting it.

[Creating Comet applications with ASP.NET](http://www.aaronlerch.com/blog/2007/07/08/creating-comet-applications-with-aspnet/)

[Scalable COMET Combined with ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CometAsync.aspx)

> This code is not production ready; it
>   is designed to demonstrate a
>   theoretical solution to using COMET in
>   ASP.NET. This article covers the
>   server-side implementation of COMET
>   and how to combat the scalability
>   problems. To demonstrate the client
>   code, I will release a smaller article
>   soon which demonstrates a small
>   tic-tac-toe game using the COMET
>   thread pooling mechanism I mention
>   below, which should give you some idea
>   about using it in a real world
>   application.

[ASP.NET and Comet: Bringing Sockets Back](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/wxv_comet.aspx)

[ASP.NET Comet Library](http://www.pokein.com/)

Answer (score 1):

this i have done to achieve the above question to solve 
website1.aspx

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="UpdateTimer_Tick" Interval="5000">
                    </asp:Timer>
                      <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="Timer1" eventname="Tick" />
                          <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="1" 
                              EnableModelValidation="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                              <PagerSettings Visible="False" />
                              <columns>
                               <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Image" >
                                   <ControlStyle Height="500px" Width="860px" />
                                  </asp:ImageField>
                              </columns>
                          </asp:GridView>

                          <br />
                </Triggers>
                </ContentTemplate>
                           </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

website1.aspx.cs

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         LoadData();
    }

    protected void UpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int pagecount = GridView1.PageCount;
         int pageIndex = GridView1.PageIndex;
         if (pageIndex != pagecount)
         {
             GridView1.PageIndex = pageIndex + 1;
             LoadData();
             Label1.Text = "" + GridView1.PageIndex++;

         }
         if (pageIndex == pagecount-1)
         {
             pageIndex = pageIndex - pagecount;
             GridView1.PageIndex = pageIndex + 1;
             LoadData();
             Label1.Text = "" + GridView1.PageIndex++;
         }

    }
    private void LoadData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=CJ-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Online_Interaction;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select [Image] from Picture_album", connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanx for helping stackoverflow